# My compiler is not showing any error on tsc but it's not running program

Tags: node.js, typescript, backend, nodes, node-modules

And this error is appearing on running

```
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                             ^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'D:\node\node_modules\chalk\source\node_modules\' imported from D:\node\node_modules\chalk\source\index.js
←[90m    at packageMainResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:461:9)←[39m
←[90m    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:604:14)←[39m
←[90m    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:649:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:695:13)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)←[39m
←[90m    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)←[39m
←[90m    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)←[39m
←[90m    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m
}
```

Please tell me how should I run it and what changes or commands should I use.

Comment: Can you add details of your code?

Comment: this was my code

Comment: import inquirer from "inquirer";
 async function askQuestion() {
       inquirer
     .prompt([
       /* Pass your questions in here */
       {
                     type: "list",
                     name: "operator",
                     message: "Which operation do you want to perform? \n",
                     choices: [ "Addition", "Subtraction", "Multiplication", "Division"]
                 },
                 ])
     .then((answers:any) => {
        console.log(answers)
 })
 }
askQuestion();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do **NOT** post code in the comments; instead, [edit] your question to include the [properly-formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code. See [how-to-ask] for more information.